# Change(some)Link(s) Name(s) of Active Workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So, I renamed and moved some workbooks that are linked together and I need to update their xlExcelLinks on  VBA, the thing is, I have a list of the references to update, but I can't figure out how to update only the ones I need and not every reference on the book.

The initial idea was to search for matching strings between a file name and the stored reference's path. Example data:

[image: Names and Paths]

A2 Cell on Data.xlsx

[image]

Change to

[image]

I have this guide example code:

```
Sub Relink()
Dim previousFile, newFile, oldPath, newPath, Macro, altTab As String 
'Macro stores the name of the file running the macro and altTab the name of the file to update
Dim ref as xlExcelLink 'Clearly not a type of data but I need something similar
Windows(Macro).activate

    For I = 2 To 4
        oldPath = Range("L"& I).Value
        newPath = Range("M" & I).Value
        previousFile = Range("N" & I).Value
        newFile = Range("O" & I).Value

        Windows(alTab).activate
        'Somehow check for every reference avoiding itself
        If ref.Address = oldPath & "\" & previousFile Then 
            ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldPath & "\" &  previousFile, _
            NewName:=newPath & "\" &  newFile, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that on some files there could be only 1 update needed from 50ish references.

Comment: You may wish to read up on the VBA Split method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()

    'Reference to your change list.
    'ThisWorkbook is the file containing this code.
    Dim ChangeList As Range
    Set ChangeList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D4")
    
    'The workbook containing the links to change.
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Test Timesheet.xlsx")
    'If workbook isn't open use:
    'Set wrkbk = workbooks.Open(<path to workbook>)

    'Look at each link in the workbook.
    'lnk must be Variant so it can be used in the For Each loop.
    Dim lnk As Variant
    For Each lnk In wrkBk.LinkSources
        
        Dim OldPath As String
        OldPath = Left(lnk, InStrRev(lnk, "\") - 1)
        
        Dim OldFileName As String
        OldFileName = Mid(lnk, InStrRev(lnk, "\") + 1, Len(lnk))
    
        'Search for the existing path in first column of ChangeList.
        Dim FoundLink As Range
        Set FoundLink = ChangeList.Columns(1).Find(OldPath, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
        
        'If it's not found, then continue to the next link.
        'If it is found check that OldName also exists on that line, if it doesn't then continue searching.
        If Not FoundLink Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAdd As String
            firstAdd = FoundLink.Address
            Do
                If FoundLink.Offset(, 2) = OldFileName Then
                    'Found the link we're after so exit the loop.
                    Dim NewPath As String
                    NewPath = FoundLink.Offset(, 1)
                    
                    Dim NewFileName As String
                    NewFileName = FoundLink.Offset(, 3)
                    
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    'Continue searching.
                    Set FoundLink = ChangeList.Columns(1).FindNext(FoundLink)
                End If
            Loop While firstAdd <> FoundLink.Address
        
            'Make the change.
            wrkBk.ChangeLink Name:=OldPath & Application.PathSeparator & OldFileName, _
                                    NewName:=NewPath & Application.PathSeparator & NewFileName
        
        End If
    Next lnk

End Sub
```